# Need help figuring out why IPhone won't run simple code

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

I have been having a lot of problems with trying to get a javascript page to work on an iphone.  since the iphone has no console option I wrote:

https://github.com/mctrivia/debugMaster

to make my own for testing purposes.  However even the simplest of pages does not seem to work.  The below code when executed with `#test` in address bar on all devices except my iphone shows `Test Test Test Test`.  The iphone shows `Should not be visible.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=200, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>       
        <script src="/js/debugMaster.js"></script>


        <script>
        $(function() {
            debugMaster.log("test");
            debugMaster.log("test");
            debugMaster.log("test");
            debugMaster.log("test");
            });
        </script>
    </header>
    <body>
        Should not be visible.
    </body>
</html>
```

[Sample JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mctrivia/a6yjux81/)

Live page available at http://mctrivia.com/test/test.html#test

**Update**
I have been doing some testing.

fails:
https://jsfiddle.net/mctrivia/a6yjux81/

passes:
https://jsfiddle.net/mctrivia/yysphgnb/

So i know so far that
`console.log('test')`,`.show`,`.append` are not the culprets

Comment: Not sure but check if `console` is available or not. Safari by design has overriden console for incognito mode. Something similar can be the issue.

Comment: If outputtype==2 ??

Comment: I have rolled back the edit. Question should only have code related to OP. Plugin's code is not required.

Comment: at top of script when #test is in address bar that is set to 2.

Comment: @Rajesh tried commenting out all refrences to console and it still does not work on iphone.

Comment: @Rajesh I do have http://mctrivia.com/test/test.html#test live if that helps.  Your JSFiddle doesn't have the library in the code so it is not going to work.  There is no index file so all files in folder are easily accessable.

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse I have added link of library. You can check in `External Resource` tab. But if you have a working reference, just share link in question. That will help everyone in debugging

Comment: @Rajesh for the purposes of making your jsfiddle work I modified the debugMaster script to include a setOutput(2) command since jsFiddle does not seem to allow checking the hash value.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  The iPhone will not allow the use of the word `let`